# Apply Kotlin multiplatform plugin via gradle legacy plugin application

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm doing some in-depth hands-on with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile and I'm forced to apply Gradle plugins with the legacy way of applying plugins.

I'm using Kotlin DSL for Gradle and I didn't manage to include the kotlin-multiplatform plugin.

Essentially, there are two ways to include a gradle plugin in your project:

1. via [Gradle Plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) (a modern way)
2. via [legacy plugin application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application) (deprecated but more flexible).

I've basically created a very blank gradle project (`gradle init`), not related to any IDE or any other dependencies, which both are common for KMM projects - to isolate the issue as much as possible.

The **build.gradle.kts** below works just fine, when run via `./gradlew clean build` (via Plugins DSL)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") version "1.4.10"
}
kotlin {
    jvm()    
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

However, this **won't** work (via legacy plugin application):

```kotlin
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10")
  }
}
apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
kotlin {
    jvm()    
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

It fails with this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 12: kotlin {
           ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
               public fun DependencyHandler.kotlin(module: String, version: String? = ...): Any defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
               public fun PluginDependenciesSpec.kotlin(module: String): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 13:     jvm()
               ^ Unresolved reference: jvm

2 errors
```

It can't resolve the `kotlin {}` block which is essentially the entry point in KMM projects.

Interestingly, using Groovy instead of Kotlin for Gradle - works in both cases.

But I would like to use Kotlin DSL for Gradle and apply the plugins via the legacy way, since this way I can apply plugins dynamically, i.e. under certain conditions.

Comment: Is there a minimum version of gradle plugin that supports kotlin?

Comment: I didn't even know this existed, but maybe you need to apply the kotlin dsl plugin? https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use `apply false` in the plugins DSL and call `apply` conditionally. `Apply` alone will **NEVER** work with Kotlin DSL, it only works with dynamic Groovy. Kotlin can work like Groovy if you also use the plugins DSL + `apply false` in it.
Example:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") apply false // Applied conditionally later
}
```

For more detailed discussion of the problem check [this](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C3PQML5NU/p1604523901315000).

Comment: Yes. That was me who started the thread initially. Thanks for bringing this here, I forgot to do it.